# How to compile C# file without a project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, compilation

Is there a way in VS2013 to compile a C# file without a project or solution?

This is useful, e.g. in editing some C# code quickly while preparing a Stack Overflow answer while scrubbing corporate IP from the file (without risking any harm to the "real project").

The build toolbar is grayed-out.

I know one can occasionally see squiggles for errors.

Any other simple ideas?

Comment: You might want to try using [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)

Comment: http://ideone.com/ provides a C# compiler

Comment: I use the [Far Manager](http://farmanager.com/index.php?l=en) (I like the build-in editor) with command-line compiler of .NET. (`csc.exe`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use https://dotnetfiddle.net/

You can specify different things in it. It is best for writing fast answers, also you can post link with your saved work. It is similar to jsfiddle if you aware of it.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about .NET Fiddle. There is also [ScriptCS](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ProjectlessScriptedCWithScriptCSAndRoslyn.aspx), which installs on your system and allows you to have each line you run interpreted. I find it useful for things like quickly playing with string formats, double rounding issues, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Snippet Compiler. You can download it from below URL.

http://www.sliver.com/dotnet/SnippetCompiler/

Its a stand alone light weight small application.

If you have Mono C# installed then C# REPL is awesome tool to execute small chunk of c# code.

http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/repl/